# Is it possible to disable gamepad button mapping in UWP apps for Xbox?

Tags: uwp, xbox

I am trying to write a game on UWP platform. Problem is: I need to bind Gamepad B and Escape to two different actions. E.g. Escape should always close current whatever, but Gamepad B should only do that unless my game handles it for a different purpose.

However, in KeyDown on Xbox pressing Gamepad B is always visible as Escape.

Comment: What appmodel are you using? In Direct3D appmodel applications, there's no keyboard mapping from the gamepad.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative I came up with is to handle `KeyDown` on particular controls, and check `eventArgs.OriginalKey`. Then in handler you can detect mapping (because `OriginalKey` won't match `Key`), and set `eventArgs.Handled = true` to avoid key processing.

Comment: This does not handle `VirtualKey.GamepadLeftTrigger`. It never even fires :(

Answer (score 0):

I think KeyRoutedEventArgs and OriginalKey is what you're looking for. Here is a sample that work for me in my app:

```
    private void StackPanel_KeyUp(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.OriginalKey == VirtualKey.GamepadB)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Lets me know if it works for you, I can provide more detail sample